# Hard Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality, lagrange-multiplier, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a,b,c,d$ be positive Real numbers, such that $ab+bc+cd+da+ac+bd=6abcd$.

Prove that $a+b+c+d-2\sqrt{2}abcd \leqslant 4-2\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Plausible observation: the constraints and the expression are symmetric in $a, b, c, d$ so I would expect the critical points to be located at points where $a = b = c = d = x$. Thus the constraint gives $6x^2 = 6x^4$ and $x = -1, 0, 1$. But they are positive so $x = 1$ and the expression is $1 + 1 + 1 + 1 - 2\sqrt 2 = 4 - 2 \sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 2):

We'll replace $a$ with $\frac{1}{a}$, $b$ with $\frac{1}{b}$, $c$ with $\frac{1}{c}$ and $d$ with $\frac{1}{d}$.

Hence, the condition gives $ab+ac+bc+ad+bd+cd=6$ and we need to prove that
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}-\frac{2\sqrt2}{abcd}\leq4-2\sqrt2$$ or
$$(4-2\sqrt2)abcd+2\sqrt2\geq abc+abd+acd+bcd.$$
We'll prove that this inequality is true even for all non-negatives $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ such that

$ab+ac+bc+ad+bd+cd=6$.

Indeed, let $$f(a,b,c,d,\lambda)=(4-2\sqrt2)abcd+2\sqrt2-abc-abd-acd-bcd+$$
$$+\lambda(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd-6).$$
But $f$ is a continuous function and $$A=\left\{(a,b,c,d,\lambda)\big|a\geq0,b\geq0,c\geq0,d\geq0,\sum\limits_{sym}ab=24\right\}$$
is a compact.

Thus, $f$ gets on $A$ the minimal value in some point $(a,b,c,d,\lambda)$,

which happens in the following cases.

1. $abcd=0$.

Let $d=0$.

Hence, by AM-GM
$$abc=\sqrt{a^2b^2c^2}=\sqrt{ab\cdot ac\cdot bc}\leq\sqrt{\left(\frac{ab+ac+bc}{3}\right)^3}=\sqrt8=2\sqrt2$$

2. $abcd\neq0$ and
   $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial c}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial d}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda}=0,$$
   which gives
   $$(4-2\sqrt2)bcd-bc-bd-cd+\lambda(b+c+d)=0$$
   and similar or
   $$(4-2\sqrt2)abcd-abc-abd-acd+\lambda(ab+ac+ad)=0,$$
   which gives
   $$-abc-abd-acd+\lambda(ab+ac+ad)=-abc-abd-bcd+\lambda(ab+bc+bd)$$ or
   $$(a-b)\left(\lambda(c+d)-cd\right)=0.$$
   By the same way we can get that in the minimum point $(a,b,c,d,\lambda)$ holds:
   $$(a-c)\left(\lambda(b+d)-bd\right)=0,$$
   $$(a-d)\left(\lambda(b+c)-bc\right)=0,$$
   $$(b-c)\left(\lambda(a+d)-ad\right)=0,$$
   $$(b-d)\left(\lambda(a+c)-ac\right)=0$$ and 
   $$(c-d)\left(\lambda(a+b)-ab\right)=0.$$
   2.1 If $a=b=c=d$ then $a=1$ and the inequality is obviously true.

2.2 If $a\neq b$, $a\neq c$ and $a\neq d$ so we obtain:
$$\lambda(c+d)-cd=0,$$
$$\lambda(b+d)-bd=0$$ and
$$\lambda(b+c)-bc=0,$$
which gives
$$\frac{bc}{b+c}=\frac{bd}{b+d}=\frac{cd}{c+d}$$ or
$$\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{d}=\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}$$ or
$$b=c=d.$$
Hence, the condition gives $a=\frac{2-b^2}{b}$, where $0<b<\sqrt2$ and we need to prove that
$$(4-2\sqrt2)\cdot\frac{2-b^2}{b}\cdot b^3+2\sqrt2\geq \frac{2-b^2}{b}\cdot3b^2+b^3,$$
which is
$$(b-1)^2(\sqrt2-b)(\sqrt2b+1+\sqrt2)\geq0;$$
2.3 $a=b.$

If we want to get something new, we can get $a\neq c$ and $a\neq d$, which gives
$$\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{d}=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$$ or
$$d=c.$$
Hence, the condition gives $a^2+4ac+c^2=6$ and we need to prove that
$$(2-\sqrt2)a^2c^2+\sqrt2\geq(a+c)ac.$$
Let $a+c=2u$ and $ac=v^2$.

Hence, the condition gives $v^2+2u^2=3$ and since $u^2\geq v^2=3-2u^2$, we obtain $u\geq1$.

Id est, we need to prove that
$$(2-\sqrt2)v^4+\sqrt2\geq2uv^2$$ or
$$(2-\sqrt2)(3-2u^2)^2+\sqrt2\geq2u(3-2u^2)$$ or
$$(u-1)((4-2\sqrt2)u^3+(6-2\sqrt2)u^2-(6-4\sqrt2)u-9+4\sqrt2)\geq0,$$
which is true for $u\geq1$.

Indeed, the polynomial $(4-2\sqrt2)u^3+(6-2\sqrt2)u^2-(6-4\sqrt2)u-9+4\sqrt2$

has one changing of coefficients signs, which by rule of Descartes says that

this polynomial has unique positive root.

Thus,
$$ (4-2\sqrt2)u^3+(6-2\sqrt2)u^2-(6-4\sqrt2)u-9+4\sqrt2\geq$$
$$\geq(4-2\sqrt2)+(6-2\sqrt2)-(6-4\sqrt2)-9+4\sqrt2=4\sqrt2-5>0$$
Done!